# ADMOB: Ad is showing on Emulator but not on real device

Tags: android, admob

So, I tried inserting an ad in my app. The test ad is visible on emulator but not on the real device. This question may seem like duplicate but it isn't. I have looked many questions regarding that but  they aren't relevant to me. I seem to get everything right  on emulator  but not on real device. Then I debugged the app on my moto G4 and still no ad.

On my activity:

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-4408797825766729~9067984003");
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

On the layout xml:

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    ads:adSize="LARGE_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-4408797825766729/5546529636" />
```

other than this I didn't code anything related to ads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you Have created/added new app on admob it will take time to show ads on your  app.
 and make sure you have this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: How much will it take figuratively? If it is about a week then I can relax. The app is four days old with two people active on it but no one has reported any ad.

Comment: I mean to say created ads from admob
usually take 4-5hrs after you created ads on admob 
As  you said you can see it in Emulator it mean nothing is wrong with your code.

Comment: It took me 24-48 hours before I started seeing real ads appear after creating the account and linking the app to it. You'll also be able to see in the logcat whether or not an ad is being requested and what the result was

Comment: Finally, after a week, it started showing ads. I don't know why it took so long, but apparently if your code is right, you will see ads sooner or later.

Comment: Ya , i too have written the AdMob code almost 4 hours ago, but still the real device isn't showing any ads.